# How to attempt a cast in TypeScript, and return if unsuccessful?

Tags: typescript, casting

I'm trying to write some shape classes with a generic `collides` function, such that I can attempt to see if two random shapes collide. I'm trying something like this:

```
function circleCircleCollision(x1: number, y1: number, r1: number, x2: number, y2: number, r2: number) { return true; }
function circleLineCollision(cx: number, cy: number, cr: number, x1: number, y1: number, x2: number, y2: number) { return true;  }

abstract class Shape {
  abstract collidesWith(shape: Shape): boolean;
}

class Circle extends Shape {
  constructor(public x = 0, public y = 0, public r = 0) { super(); }

  collidesWith(shape: Shape) {
    let circle = shape as Circle;
    if (circle) {
      // this always runs, even though it should only run when the cast is successful
      return circleCircleCollision(this.x, this.y, this.r, circle.x, circle.y, circle.r);
    }

    let line = shape as Line;
    if (line) {
      return circleLineCollision(this.x, this.y, this.r, line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2);
    }

    return false;
  }
}

class Line extends Shape {
  constructor(public x1 = 0, public y1 = 0, public x2 = 0, public y2 = 0) { super(); }

  collidesWith(shape: Shape) { return true; }
}
```

Unfortunately, as the comment notes, the first `if` always runs, because the cast always succeeds. But I only want that `if` to run if the passed shape is *actually* a circle. Is this possible to do? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change

`if (circle)`

to

`if (circle instanceof Circle)`

or just

`(shape instanceof Circle)`

As TypeScript does not change the value itself during types casting .

More info about instanceof operator can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof?retiredLocale=uk)

Comment: Oh, you need to cast and then _also_ do `instanceof`? Alright, kind of strange but if it works it works. Thanks!

Comment: you may not even cast :)
just using instanceof would do the job

Comment: Well, I still need the cast don't I? Because I need to access the casted circle's member variables afterwards to determine if it actually collides with the other circle.

Comment: for access to the circle's properties you'll need to cast the type . But it's not important for the check for instanceof .
Maybe even a bit more accurate option would be checking for instance of and only then casting the type .

Comment: Casting is not needed, after doing `instanceof` you have access to the `Circle` properties (inside the if statement). It's called a type guard. I think you can even do `if (shape is Circle) { console.log(shape.radius)}`. Typescript is smart like that!